# postgresql additional indexes in replica

Tags: postgresql

How Can I create additional indexes in PostgreSQL12 replica like MySQL?

In MySQL, I can create additional indexes to avoid the overhead of an index refreshment in master keeping high read throughput for a replica.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with streaming replication, since that maintains a faithful physical copy of the primary server.

But you can do it easily if you use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html).